# Как в openpyxl поменять формат числа?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поменять формат чисел в определенной колонке, чтобы было `'0.00'`. Пыталась, с помощью `_cell.number_format='0.00'` - но не выходит

```
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Документ_1.xlsx')
ws=wb['лист_1']
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('Документ_2.xlsx')
ws2=wb2['лист_из_др_книги']
_cell.number_format='0.00'

for row in range(4,8):
ws2.cell(row+1,30).value=ws.cell(row,4).value
print(ws2.cell(row+1,column=30).value)
wb2.save(filename='Документ_2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь атрибутом [`cell.number_format`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-number-formats). Если применить его к ячейке, обращаясь по адресу ячейки, а не к копии ячейки в памяти, то все должно правильно работать.

Пример:

```
ws['A4'].number_format = '0.00'
```

PS [Warning](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell):

> When a worksheet is created in memory, it contains no cells. They are
>   created when first accessed.
>
> Because of this feature, scrolling through cells instead of accessing
>   them directly will create them all in memory, even if you don’t assign
>   them a value.
>
> Something like
>
> ```
> >>> for x in range(1,101):
> ...        for y in range(1,101):
> ...            ws.cell(row=x, column=y)
> ```
>
> will create 100x100 cells in memory, for nothing.

Comment: к сожалению не сработало(  ws['D4'].number_format='0.00'
print(ws['D4'].value)

Comment: @user327535, проверять надо непосредственно в Excel файле, а не в `ws['D4'].value`

Comment: проверила в экселе, к сожалению, не работает все равно (

Comment: @user327535, попробуйте изменить формат для одной ячейки и сохраните файл: wb2.save(filename='Документ_2.xlsx') - у меня все работает...

Comment: все правильно - сработало, а подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать код, чтобы применить такое к диапазону ячеек?

Comment: @user327535, я думаю лучше задать отдельный вопрос с небольшим примером входных и выходных данных... Решение будет отличаться в зависимости от конкретной задачи. Например диапазоном может быть строка, столбец или прямоугольник состоящий из набора ячеек...